# FFMPEG - avcodec_decode_video2 return "Invalid frame dimensions 0x0"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to build a simple FFMPEG MPEG2 video PES decoder on ANDROID using the ffmpeg/doc/example/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html.

I am using FFMPEG version 2.0!

I initialize the ffmpeg system with the following code:

```
int VideoPlayer::_setupFFmpeg()
{
    int rc;
    AVCodec *codec;

    av_register_all();
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
    if(NULL == codec){
        LOGE("_setupFFmpeg. No codec!");
        return -1;
    }
    LOGI("found: %p. name: %s", codec, codec->name);

    _video_dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if(NULL == _video_dec_ctx){
        LOGE("_setupFFmpeg. Could not allocate codec context space!");
        return -1;
    }
    _video_dec_ctx->debug = FF_DEBUG_PICT_INFO;
    if(codec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED) _video_dec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

    rc = avcodec_open2(_video_dec_ctx, codec, NULL);
    if(rc < 0) {
        LOGE("_setupFFmpeg. Could not open the codec: %s!", _video_dec_ctx->codec->name);
        return -1;
    }

    av_init_packet(&_avpkt);

    if(NULL == _video_frame) _video_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if(NULL == _video_frame){
        LOGE("_setupFFmpeg. Could not allocate memory for the video frame!");
        return -1;
    }

    LOGI("_setupFFmpeg(exit)");
    return 0;
}
```

And then just having a loop that is continuously sending PES packets at the decoder calling this function:

```
int VideoPlayer::_playVideoPacket(PesPacket *packet)
{
    int len, frameReady;
    _avpkt.data = packet->buf;
    _avpkt.size = packet->info.bufferSize;
    while(_avpkt.size){
        len = avcodec_decode_video2(_video_dec_ctx, _video_frame, &frameReady, &_avpkt);
        if(len < 0){
            LOGE("FFW_decodeVideo");
            return len;
        }
        if(frameReady){
            //Draw the picture...
        }
        _avpkt.size -= len;
        _avpkt.data += len;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

But when I run the code I get:
"Invalid frame dimensions 0x0" error from FFMPEG after calling avcodec_decode_video2().

It seems that I am not setting up the codec correctly. The MpegEncContext in Mpeg1Context in mpeg12dec.c is not setup correctly. What do I have to do to setup MpegEncContext correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your variable names, you are passing a pes packet into decode_video. This is wrong. You must pass in a raw ES packet (no pes header) The easiest way to do this is use avformat and av_read_frame() to fill AVPacket for you. If you are using your own format demuxer, you must get down to the Raw ES layer. You may also need to set the PTS DTS values.

Note: I do not know mpeg2 very well, but some codecas require you to configure the extradata values in the codec context also.

Comment: Exactly. That was the problem!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Stand Alone Example**

Just created a stand alone slice of code that we use locally to wrap libav for video decoding (there is some new hwacceleration portions that are buggy/in testing, feel free to pull that stuff out)

Here's an example of the wrapper class header:

```
class SchneiderVideoAV {
public:
    SchneiderVideoAV();
    SchneiderVideoAV(const string &fileName);

    ~SchneiderVideoAV();
    void cleanUp();

    int initialize(const string &fileName);
    // loads cube from framestart->end, defaults -1,-1 load entire video into cube
    int loadCube(CSCubeBGRA *pCube, int frameStart=-1, int frameEnd=-1);
    int loadFrame(CSFrameBGRA *pFrame, int frameIndex);

    AVFormatContext    *m_pFormatCtx;
    AVCodecContext     *m_pCodecCtx;
    AVCodec            *m_pCodec;
    AVFrame            *m_pFrame; 
    AVFrame            *m_pFrameBGRA;
    int                 m_numBytes;
    uint8_t            *m_pBuffer;
    int                 m_VideoStream;
    int64_t             m_TimeBase;


    AVDictionary       *m_pOptionsDict;
    struct SwsContext  *m_pSWSCtx;
    string              m_FileName;
    int                 m_Width;
    int                 m_Height;
    int                 m_MaxFrames;
    int                 m_Good;
    float               m_FPS;
    double              m_StartTime;
    double              m_RotationDegrees;
};
```

and the implementation:

```
SchneiderVideoAV::SchneiderVideoAV()
{
    m_Good          = 0;

    m_pFormatCtx    = NULL;
    m_pCodecCtx     = NULL;
    m_pCodec        = NULL;
    m_pFrame        = NULL; 
    m_pFrameBGRA    = NULL;
    m_pBuffer       = NULL;
    m_pOptionsDict  = NULL;
    m_pSWSCtx       = NULL;
    m_VideoStream   = -1;

    m_Width = m_Height = m_MaxFrames = m_numBytes = 0;
}


SchneiderVideoAV::SchneiderVideoAV(const string &fileName)
{
    initialize(fileName);
}


SchneiderVideoAV::~SchneiderVideoAV()
{
    cleanUp();
}

void SchneiderVideoAV::cleanUp()
{
    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();     

    // Free the RGB image
    if (m_pBuffer) av_free(m_pBuffer);
    if (m_pFrameBGRA) av_free(m_pFrameBGRA);

    // Free the YUV? frame
    if (m_pFrame) av_free(m_pFrame);

    // Close the codec
    if (m_pCodecCtx) avcodec_close(m_pCodecCtx);

    // Close the video file
    if (m_pFormatCtx) avformat_close_input(&m_pFormatCtx);

    // free dictionary
    if (m_pOptionsDict) av_dict_free(&m_pOptionsDict);

    m_pBuffer       = NULL;
    m_pFrameBGRA    = NULL;
    m_pFrame        = NULL; 
    m_pCodecCtx     = NULL;
    m_pFormatCtx    = NULL;
    m_pOptionsDict  = NULL;

    m_Width = m_Height = m_MaxFrames = m_numBytes = 0;    

}

int SchneiderVideoAV::initialize(const string &fileName)
{
    LogStream mout(LOG_DEBUG,"SchneiderVideoAV.initialize.ccode");

    m_FileName          = fileName;
    m_Good              = 1;

    m_pFormatCtx        = NULL;
    m_pCodecCtx         = NULL;
    m_pCodec            = NULL;
    m_pFrame            = NULL; 
    m_pFrameBGRA        = NULL;
    m_pBuffer           = NULL;
    m_pOptionsDict      = NULL;
    m_pSWSCtx           = NULL;
    m_VideoStream       = -1;
    m_RotationDegrees   = 0.0;

    m_Width = m_Height = m_MaxFrames = m_numBytes = 0;


    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    // Open video file
    if(avformat_open_input(&m_pFormatCtx, m_FileName.c_str(), NULL, NULL)!=0) {
        m_Good = 0;
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL; // Couldn't open file
    }

    // Retrieve stream information
    if(avformat_find_stream_info(m_pFormatCtx, NULL)<0) {
        m_Good = 0;
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL; // Couldn't find stream information
    }

    // Dump information about file onto standard error
    int64_t durationInt = m_pFormatCtx->duration;
    double durationSeconds = (double)durationInt / AV_TIME_BASE;

    // av_dump_format(m_pFormatCtx, 0, m_FileName.c_str(), 0);

    int i = 0;

    // Find the first video stream
    for(i=0; i< (int) m_pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        // cout << "checking streams for video " << m_pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type;
        // cout << " av media type " << AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO << endl;
        if(m_pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            if (m_VideoStream == -1) {
                m_VideoStream=i;
                // av_dump_format(m_pFormatCtx, 0, m_FileName.c_str(), 0);
                AVDictionaryEntry *pDictEntry = av_dict_get(m_pFormatCtx->streams[i]->metadata, "rotate", NULL, 0);
                if (pDictEntry) m_RotationDegrees = atof(pDictEntry->value);
                // cout << "Dict_entry for rotate from metatdata in stream " << pDictEntry->value << " rotation degrees " << m_RotationDegrees << endl;
            }
            if (VERBOSE_LOGGING) mout << "found a video stream " << i << LogStream::endl;
            // break;
        }
    }
    if(m_VideoStream==-1) {
        m_Good = 0;
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL; // Didn't find a video stream
    }

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    m_pCodecCtx=m_pFormatCtx->streams[m_VideoStream]->codec;
    m_FPS = av_q2d(m_pFormatCtx->streams[m_VideoStream]->avg_frame_rate);
    // cout << "duration seconds " << durationSeconds << " frame # ";

    int frameCount = 0;
    if (m_pFormatCtx->streams[m_VideoStream]->nb_frames > 0) {
        frameCount = m_pFormatCtx->streams[m_VideoStream]->nb_frames;
    }
    else {
        frameCount = floor(durationSeconds * m_FPS);
    } 
    // cout << "frameCount " << frameCount << endl;

    m_TimeBase = (int64_t(m_pCodecCtx->time_base.num) * AV_TIME_BASE) / int64_t(m_pCodecCtx->time_base.den);

    m_Width     = m_pCodecCtx->width;
    m_Height    = m_pCodecCtx->height;
    m_MaxFrames = frameCount;

    // cout << " avg fps " << m_FPS << endl;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    AVPixelFormat usedPixelFormat;
    if (m_pCodecCtx->codec_id == CODEC_ID_H264) {
        m_pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("h264_vda");
        usedPixelFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_VDA;
        m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = usedPixelFormat;
    }
    else {
        m_pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(m_pCodecCtx->codec_id);
        usedPixelFormat = m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    }

    // ignore this if you are not messing with hwaccel decoding
    cout << "about to call ff_find_hwaccel codec, id, pix_fmt name, value " << m_pCodec->name << "," << m_pCodecCtx->codec_id;
    cout << "," << pixFmt2String(usedPixelFormat) << "," << usedPixelFormat << endl;
    m_pCodecCtx->hwaccel = ff_find_hwaccel(m_pCodecCtx->codec_id,usedPixelFormat);

    if(m_pCodec==NULL) {
        mout.setLog(LOG_ERR);
        mout << "SchneiderVideoAV::initialize Unsupported codec!" << LogStream::endl;
        mout.setLog(LOG_DEBUG);
        m_Good = 0;
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL; // Codec not found
    }


    // Open codec
    if(avcodec_open2(m_pCodecCtx, m_pCodec, &m_pOptionsDict)<0) {
        mout.setLog(LOG_ERR);
        mout << "SchneiderVideoAV::initialize Unable to open codec" << LogStream::endl;
        mout.setLog(LOG_DEBUG);
        m_Good = 0;        
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL; // Could not open codec
    }

    // Allocate video frame
    m_pFrame=av_frame_alloc();

    // Allocate an AVFrame structure
    m_pFrameBGRA=av_frame_alloc();
    if(m_pFrameBGRA==NULL) {
        m_Good = 0;        
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL;
    }


    // Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
    m_numBytes=avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_BGRA, m_pCodecCtx->width,
                                    m_pCodecCtx->height);

    m_pBuffer=(uint8_t *)av_malloc(m_numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));


    if (VERBOSE_LOGGING) mout << "ZOMG right before m_pSWSCtx, and sws_getContext m_pCodecCtx width, height, FrameCount " << m_pCodecCtx->width << " , " << m_pCodecCtx->height << " pix_fmt " << m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt << LogStream::endl;
    if (m_pCodecCtx->hwaccel == NULL) {
        m_pSWSCtx = sws_getContext
            (
                m_pCodecCtx->width,
                m_pCodecCtx->height,
                m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                // usedPixelFormat,
                m_pCodecCtx->width,
                m_pCodecCtx->height,
                PIX_FMT_BGRA,
                SWS_BILINEAR,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL
            );
    }

    // cout << "m_pCodecCtx width,height pix_fmt " << m_pCodecCtx->width;
    // cout << "," << m_pCodecCtx->height << " pix_fmt " << m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    // cout << " PIX_FMT_BGRA " << PIX_FMT_BGRA << endl; 


    VIDEO_IO_MUTEX.unlock();

    return VID_PROCESS_OK;
}

int SchneiderVideoAV::loadCube(CSCubeBGRA *pCube, int frameStart, int frameEnd)
{
    // cout << "SchneiderVideoAV::loadCube frameStart,frameEnd " << frameStart << "," << frameEnd << endl;

    cleanUp();
    initialize(m_FileName);

    LogStream mout(LOG_DEBUG,"SchneiderVideoAV.loadCube.ccode");
    if (m_Good) {
        // cout << "max frames " << m_MaxFrames << endl;
        if (frameEnd >= m_MaxFrames) frameEnd = m_MaxFrames - 1;
        if (frameEnd < 0) frameEnd = m_MaxFrames - 1;
        if (frameStart > frameEnd) frameStart = frameEnd;
        if (frameStart < 0) frameStart = 0;
        int frameCount = frameEnd - frameStart + 1;

        // cout << "SchneiderVideoAV::loadCube width,height,frameCount " << m_Width << "," << m_Height << "," << frameCount << endl;
        pCube->Set(m_Width,m_Height,frameCount,m_FPS);

        // Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in m_pFrameRGB
        // Note that m_pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
        // of AVPicture
        avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)m_pFrameBGRA, m_pBuffer, PIX_FMT_BGRA,
                     m_pCodecCtx->width, m_pCodecCtx->height);

        // couldn't get seek to work, need to keep track of key/iFrames and read up to desired frame
        // if (frameStart > 0) {
        //     int64_t seekTarget = int64_t(frameStart) * m_TimeBase;

        //     if(av_seek_frame(m_pFormatCtx, -1, seekTarget, AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY) < 0) {
        //         mout << "averror av_seek_frame failed for file " << m_FileName.c_str() << LogStream::endl;            
        //         return -1;
        //     }
        // }

        int iFrame = 0;
        int iAbsoluteFrame = 0;

        int count_errs=0,skip_packets=0;
        const int max_number_of_attempts = 200;
        const int max_skipped_packets=10000;
        int frameFinished;

        bool FinishedReading = false;
        while(!FinishedReading) {
            AVPacket packet;
            int ret = av_read_frame(m_pFormatCtx, &packet);

            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) ) {
                skip_packets++;
                if (skip_packets > max_skipped_packets) {
                    mout << "averror exceeded max number of for file " << m_FileName.c_str() << LogStream::endl;
                    av_dump_format(m_pFormatCtx,0,m_FileName.c_str(),0); 
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }

            // if (packet.stream_index == m_VideoStream) cout << "m_VideoStream " << m_VideoStream << " packet.stream_index " << packet.stream_index << " skip packets " << skip_packets << endl;

            if( packet.stream_index != m_VideoStream )
            {
                av_free_packet (&packet);
                // cout << "this packet isn't a m_VideoStream " << packet.stream_index << " skipped packets " << skip_packets;
                // cout << " frames " << frameCount << " nb_frames " << (unsigned long)(m_pFormatCtx->streams[m_VideoStream]->nb_frames) << endl;
                skip_packets++;
                if (skip_packets > max_skipped_packets) {
                    mout << "skipped packets (non Video Stream packets) exceeded max number of skipped packets for file " << m_FileName.c_str() << LogStream::endl;
                    av_dump_format(m_pFormatCtx,0,m_FileName.c_str(),0); 
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }

            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(m_pCodecCtx, m_pFrame, &frameFinished, 
                         &packet);

            // Did we get a video frame?
            if(frameFinished) {

                iAbsoluteFrame++;
                if (iAbsoluteFrame > frameStart && iFrame < frameCount) { // skip frames until frameStart

                    // Convert the image from its native format to BGRA
                    if (m_pCodecCtx->hwaccel) {
                        m_pSWSCtx = sws_getCachedContext
                            (
                                m_pSWSCtx,
                                m_pCodecCtx->width,
                                m_pCodecCtx->height,
                                m_pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                m_pCodecCtx->width,
                                m_pCodecCtx->height,
                                PIX_FMT_BGRA,
                                SWS_BILINEAR,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL                                
                            );
                    }
                    if (!m_pFrame->data[0]) {
                        cout << "skip this frame its not ready to be scaled" << endl;
                    }
                    else {

                        sws_scale
                        (
                                m_pSWSCtx,
                                (uint8_t const * const *)m_pFrame->data,
                                m_pFrame->linesize,
                                0,
                                m_pCodecCtx->height,
                                m_pFrameBGRA->data,
                                m_pFrameBGRA->linesize
                        );


                        if (!m_pFrameBGRA->data[0]) {
                            mout << "averror unable to get libav frame data = NULL done reading file " << m_FileName.c_str() << LogStream::endl;
                            FinishedReading = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            // Dump the frame to the console rgba order
                            // DumpFrame(m_pFrameBGRA, m_pCodecCtx->width, m_pCodecCtx->height);

                            // cout << "about to set frame " << iFrame << endl;
                            // bool usedPacket = false;
                            int64_t pts = packet.pts;
                            double frameTime = 0.0;
                            if (iFrame) frameTime = pCube->m_FrameTimes[iFrame-1] + 1.0/m_FPS;
                            if (pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
                                if (packet.stream_index == m_VideoStream) {
                                    AVRational *pTimeBase = &m_pFormatCtx->streams[packet.stream_index]->time_base;
                                    if (!iFrame) m_StartTime = av_q2d(*pTimeBase) * packet.pts;
                                    frameTime = av_q2d(*pTimeBase) * packet.pts - m_StartTime;
                                    // usedPacket = true;
                                }
                            }
                            // m_pFrameBGRA->data[0] is a pointer to a BGRA frame
                            pCube->m_FrameTimes[iFrame] = frameTime;
                            pCube->SetFrame(iFrame++,m_pFrameBGRA->data[0]);

                            bool lastFrame = false;
                            if (frameEnd >= 0 && iAbsoluteFrame > frameEnd) lastFrame = true;

                            if( iFrame >= frameCount || lastFrame ) {
                                FinishedReading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else {
                count_errs++;
                if (count_errs > max_number_of_attempts) {
                    mout << "unable to read video file " << m_FileName.c_str() << " dumping metadata to std out from av function" << LogStream::endl;
                    av_dump_format(m_pFormatCtx,0,m_FileName.c_str(),0); 
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
            av_free_packet(&packet);
        }


        if (count_errs > max_number_of_attempts) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (skip_packets > max_skipped_packets) {
            return -1;
        }

    }
    else { // no good return failure
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL;
    }
    return VID_PROCESS_OK;
}

int SchneiderVideoAV::loadFrame(CSFrameBGRA *pFrame, int frameIndex)
{   

    CSCubeBGRA temp;
    int status = loadCube(&temp,frameIndex,frameIndex);

    if (status != VID_PROCESS_OK) {
        return VID_PROCESS_FAIL;
    }

    pFrame->Set(temp.m_Width,temp.m_Height,temp.pFrameData(0));
    return VID_PROCESS_OK;
}
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/victusfate/8b86ec1a4fb89e77ba00)